# the ' character makes the result of importing csv file incorrect

Tags: r

I am working on a particular csv file, which have 20310 rows. I import the file using
`Dat<-data.frame(Read.table(“data.csv”,sep=”,”,header=T))`   However, the generated Dat only has less than 20000 rows. It turns out that after removing the character `‘` from the csv file, the generated Dat will have correct number of rows. I only want to know why it happens? Is there a way to correctly keeping all the rows while keeping those `‘`

Comment: Did you try playing with the "`quote`" argument at all?

Comment: I assume it's the `quote` parameter in `read.table`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
read.table(..., quote = '')
```

This will prevent `read.table` from trying to interpret quotes.